# Converting an Android ConstraintLayout back to a RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-studio, android-relativelayout, android-constraintlayout

I have a ConstraintLayout that I would like to convert back to a RelativeLayout and then nest a ConstraintLayout within that RelativeLayout. Android Studio has a built in method of converting a RelativeLayout to a ConstraintLayout:

[image]

But I don't see a method to perform the reverse operation (Back to a RelativeLayout) What would be the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to do this automatically.

I hope you run a version control system like git and can revert your changes.

If not you have to undo your changes in Android Studio (`Cmd` + `Shift` + `a` => `Local History`) or do it manually.

Comment: I can no longer undo the changes in Android Studio, but I am using git. I guess I was just wondering if there was a way built into the IDE to accomplish this without reverting.

Answer (score 2):

Just change constraint layout to relative layout inside XML file.